# Where can I find a good repository of semi-transparent tiles for web?

Tags: website-design, css, tiles

I have been looking frequently for a site, a service that provides a repository of semi-transparent tiling backgrounds. I've found some grain generators, but I would like some more things that I could use for effects like; etchings, smoke, blur, rust or dirt.

I love these kind of background tiles as it can really add a lot of depth to your design. It's just so hard to find a go-to place where I can buy and download.

Comment: I don't think transparent backgrounds are in high demand, since you can make any background transparent very easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been finding some really great ones on http://subtlepatterns.com/. They're all free to use, provided you credit them somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: they have good ones, but i wish i knew more.